# Recycler View Layout Not Showed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have created a xml for the layout that contains cardview and recycler view.After I inflate the view into fragment everything work as normally.The scenario is when I clicked the button the adapter will push new data into recycler view.The data is pushed normally but the recyclerview does not show to the layout cause the layout_width and height.
My question is how to make the recycler view display properly

I thinks the wrong is in my id =recycler_view_daftar_barang
Sorry for my bad english
Here is My XML Code

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_tanggal_so"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_tanggal_so"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:hint="@string/tanggal_so" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_pelanggan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/auto_complete_pelanggan"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/pelanggan_nama" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_keterangan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_keterangan"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:hint="@string/keterangan" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_daftar_barang"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/so_tambah_barang"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/barang_tambah" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_subtotal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_subtotal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:hint="@string/subtotal" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_pajak"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_pajak"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/pajak"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_potongan"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_potongan"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/potongan" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think it's better if you post the code of your `Fragment` as well, which deals with above layout.

Comment: For testing point of view try to set height to "100 dp" and check whether it's visible now or not.

Comment: You should use HierarchyViewer to inspect the layout at runtime: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer